# PHP switch statement for HTML form handling not working as expected

Tags: php, html, forms, switch-statement

I am trying to get a simple switch statement to work with my form, but my case statements are being ignored except for the default message which in Chrome comes up and displays no matter what the form input. In in Firefox when I hit submit it goes to the root folder above my working folder in the hierarchy.  Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>A Simple Switch Form</title>
    </head>
<body> 

    <form name="GetForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
        1) What are the colors of the U.S. Flag?
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="a" />
        a) red, white and blue
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="b" />
        b) yellow, red and blue
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="c" />
        c) blue, green and amber
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="GO" />
        <input type="reset" value="RESET" />
    </form>
</body>
</html> 
<?

switch ($_POST['Question1']) {
case 'a':
    echo "You are correct.";    
    break;
case 'b':
    echo "Your answer is incorrect";
    break;
case 'c':
    echo "Your answer is incorrect";
    break;
case '':
    echo "Please enter a response to the question.";
    break;
default:
    echo "Welcome to my simplest of php SWITCH scripts";
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you setting an action at all? Default action is to self

Comment: It's `$_POST`, not `$POST`

Comment: Well I just feel like an idiot, but thank you for getting me past that. I've updated the code above, and now the default message does not display- ideas? Also, the 'reset' button doesn't work at all and even when I refresh the browser manually the message from the previous form entry stays on the page. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Put quotes in the two define statements. Obviously php error reporting for notices is not on otherwise you would notice it. Anyway it works for me.

Comment: Sorry- I didn't use those two define statements- should have removed them for this question.

Comment: ALSO- Firefox is still directing all actions to the root folder- see original question last sentence.

Comment: I want to accept andrewsi's answer but cannot. Thanks for the quick/easy answer. My other issues were never addressed so I will continue to seek answers on my own. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to the file itself, you can just use `action="?"` (or no action).

Then you'd better use *long* PHP tags: `<?php`, not `<?`.

And if you output something after the `</html>` document close, it *could* be that it isn't displayed. For sure that's not correct HTML.

Constants should be quoted:

```
define('ERROR',  ...
```

and since the code is *always* executed, you must be sure to only examine `$_POST` if it's appropriate:

```
    </form>
<?php

define('ERROR', 'No answer was input for this question. Please select and answer.');
define('GREETING', 'Welcome to my simplest of php forms.');

if (!array_key_exists('Question1', $_POST)) {
    exit(); // We're just displaying the form.
}

switch ($_POST['Question1']) {
    ...
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** -- one thing I had forgotten. If there is *no* answer, the 'Question1' entry in the `$_POST` array is not equal to '' -- it's *missing altogether*. You need to explicitly test for that case, or assign an empty string if it does not exist. For example:

```
// Create an "answer" array from _POST. Missing entries will be added with
// a default value.

$answer = array_merge(array(
     'Question1'   => '',
     'Question2'   => '',
), $_POST);

switch($answer['Question1']) {
```

Finally, if your IDE doesn't allow debugging, you can just print out the content of `$_POST`:

```
default:
    print "<pre>Something strange happened, this is _POST:";
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit();
```

I'd recommend an IDE such as Eclipse w/PDT and XDebug. Yes, *now* it is a massive overkill. *These* files you can develop in Notepad, yes. But give it a couple of months of less and less trivial development, then let's talk about it again :-)

Apart from this, it *looks* like it ought to work.

## Altered code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>A Simple Switch Form</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="GetForm" method="POST">
        1) What are the colors of the U.S. Flag?
        <br /><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="a" />a) red, white and blue
        <br /><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="b" />b) yellow, red and blue
        <br /><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="c" />c) blue, green and amber
        <br /><input type="submit" name="cmd" value="GO" /><input type="reset" value="RESET" />
    </form>
<?php

define('ERROR', 'No answer was input for this question. Please select and answer.');
define('GREETING', 'Welcome to my simplest of php forms.');

/*
    The $_POST array always exists. If this page is loaded standalone, it will be
    empty. If it is loaded as reaction to a question being answered, we need a way
    to tell. It can't be the question itself, because if it was left blank, then
    we could not tell between the "standalone" and "empty answer" cases.
    So we add a field that we're sure will always be transmitted, linked to the
    submit button, by naming this button "cmd".
    Now, the presence of "cmd" in $_POST will tell us that a question has been
    answered (or attempted). Its absence will tell that we just need to show the
    question for the first time.
*/
if (!array_key_exists('cmd', $_POST)) {
    // Just showing the form.
    echo GREETING;
} else {
    // "cmd" is present, so we know that a question has been attempted.
    // Has it been answered? Now we need to check for this.
    if (!array_key_exists('Question1', $_POST)) {
        // Did not answer.
        // We replace "no answer" (Question1 not found) with "empty answer"
        // (Question1 equal to '') so that we can treat "no-answer" as any other answer.
        $_POST['Question1'] = '';
    }
    switch ($_POST['Question1']) {
        case 'a':
            echo "You are correct.";
            break;
        // b and c elicit the same reaction, so the two switch cases can be
        // written together.
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
            echo "Your answer '{$_POST['Question1']}' is incorrect";
            break;
        case '':
            echo ERROR;
            break;
        default:
            // We should not be here, because from the form one can only send
            // a, b or c, and if he does none, we receive the empty string.
            // However, it is good policy to foresee a "default" case and intercept
            // possible unforeseen circumstances.
            echo GREETING;
            break;
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Iserni- None of these helped my issues but thanks... I'm using Aptana Studio for editing.

Comment: What do you use to view results? I've uploaded the file to a server and it works as it should.

Comment: ...I'm also copying a version of the code. The changes are really cosmetic, the code worked from the start (apart from a couple of warnings and not recognizing the missing answer).

Comment: This doesn't address my concerns and goes way above my coding knowledge. I am sure at some point I will appreciate your comments but for now they only confuse me.

Comment: I am sorry. You are almost there, though. I have amended my commented code to better explain what's behind it. Feel free to comment, amend or contact me.

Comment: Iserni Thank you again for all of your time. This makes sense to me. Now, however- using your code- my form ignores all input but gives me the default message.

Comment: Can't quite fathom why. I have cut and pasted the code here: http://www.serni.org/stackoverflow/24764454.php - and it seems to work (in case I fiddle with it, by adding .txt you can download the current source code).

Comment: OK this morning it worked. Thanks SO much for hanging in there with me.